# DAS IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I have configured DAS and API Manager as per the instructions given in the documentation. I have diff docker containers running DAS and one container each for running manager,worker,publisher and store.  Although I see data in the Data Explorer in DAS UI, but in the publisher UI, I get a static HTML page. I see the following in the publisher logs. Any idea?
ERROR - usage:jag java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: Please post your complete error log.

Comment: That is all I see in the logs.

Comment: What is your APIM version? And what is the doc you followed?

Comment: APIM 1.10.0. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+REST+Client

Comment: What is your DAS version?

Answer (score 0):

This was a [known issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DAS-404) in DAS 3.0.1, and fixed in DAS 3.1.0

> This was being caused because the destination RDBMS tables were being
>   dropped by Spark during each INSERT call. This behavior has been fixed
>   in DAS 3.1.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the new version released? Could you please send me the link to download it? I cannot find it in the website

Comment: Looks like it's not officially released due to some reason. It's there in github though. https://github.com/wso2/product-das/releases

However, from APIM 2.0.0 onward, you should use APIM-Analytic Server, which is a customized version of DAS. If you use that there will be very few number of steps to setup analytics.

Comment: Looks like its a RC (wso2das-3.1.0-RC1.zip).. When will this be GA? Also is this version a stable one?

Comment: Yes it's RC1, and it failed vote due to some issues.

Comment: Sorry, but I wanted to know if this version can be used in production and if you have any  tentative dates for the GA release.

Comment: Don't use RC1 for production. GA will be released in about 2 weeks.